# OSX SFTP with Sudo?

Tags: ssh, osx, sudo, sftp

I have been given access to a server to do some legacy development work. The server is running `RedHat Enterprise Linux 6` as its OS.

To access this server, I must first SSH in with my username/password that was set up for me. There is then a service account that I need to sudo into in order to access some of the web files etc.

Normally I am used to just having a single account where I don't need to sudo into.

That being said, I like to use SFTP to transfer files and thats where I am stuck..

When I use an application like CyberDuck or Filezilla, I login using the SFTP protocol using my assigned username / password. However, I am unable to access the files and directories I need without sudo.

Are there any SFTP applications that support this for a Mac, or the protocol in general?

Comment: This server is obviously set of like that for a reason (security, privacy/protection of data/code). Rather than asking us to help you circumvent these measures, I would suggest that you contact the admin of the system to discuss possible ways to make your work easier and more convenient, without compromising whatever it is that they are protecting.

Comment: I agree to @Kusalananda's comment above. The current setup is there for a reason and when you try to access the files on SFTP via filezilla you are not completing the necessary steps (sudo to another account) to complete the transaction. Try discussing with your concern with the sysadmin

Comment: I would say this question is more about efficiency that circumvention. I already have the correct access and can SSH, Sudo, and then SCP files freely as needed. This would be different if I was asking how to access a sudo account directly that I didn't have access to.

Was simply trying to find out if there was an application that does something like SFTP Login Using Credentials > Sends sudo command, allows SFTP using the connection as the sudo user rather than my own login (the same access I have if I were to do this all through command line).

Comment: Might be easier to set up a directory on the server which is accessible both from your main account (so you can SFTP stuff into it) and from the sudo account (so you can access stuff you've SFTPed over without having to copy it between accounts)